# how to put text at center of link in d3 charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am using d3 charts v4 but I am trying to get the text at the center in the links

```
var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return "M" + project(source, source.x0, source.y0)
      + "L" + project(source, source.x0, source.y0);
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/rjvim/pen/OOOOop  => with this Eg can I get Text  at the center in line